# Hololens2 multi user capabilities

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

While following the mrtk tutorial on multi-user capabilities, there has been one CS0234 & CS0246 error that I haven't been able to avoid.

After importing PUN 2 from the asset store, all CS0246 & CS0246 errors from importing the MultiUserCapibilities package are resolved except for
[Erros](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axmeL.png)

I have followed this tutorial with my current project on Unity 2020.3.20f, the same project updated to Unity 2021, and a blank Unity 2020 LTS project following only the essential steps (switching build platform, importing MRTK foundation and OpenXR through the feature tool, and setting up MRTK and OpenXR in Unity). All of them only throw this one error. I also updated my Windows SDK and restarted my PC as many other solutions suggest.

My best guess is that this is something on Microsoft's end.

Windows 11 21H2 (OS Build 22621.1778)
Windows SDK version 2019 (10.0.10240.0)
Unity 2020.3.20f1
MRTK 2.8.3

Answer (score 0):

This **Multi-user capabilities tutorial** assumes that you have completed all modules in the [HoloLens 2 fundamentals tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/paths/beginner-hololens-2-tutorials/). Some packages are already mentioned in these modules, so are not listed in the documentation. The following are the asset packages required for this tutorial, please check.

1. MRTK/Mixed Reality Toolkit Foundation
2. MRTK/Mixed Reality OpenXR Plugin
3. MRTK/Azure Spatial Anchors SDK Core
4. MRTK/Azure Spatial Anchors SDK for Windows
5. [MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.GettingStarted.2.7.2.unitypackage](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityLearning/releases/download/getting-started-v2.7.2/MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.GettingStarted.2.7.2.unitypackage)
6. [MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.MultiUserCapabilities.2.7.2.unitypackage](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityLearning/releases/download/multi-user-capabilities-v2.7.2/MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.MultiUserCapabilities.2.7.2.unitypackage)
7. [MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.AzureSpatialAnchors.2.7.2.unitypackage](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityLearning/releases/download/azure-spatial-anchors-v2.7.2/MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.AzureSpatialAnchors.2.7.2.unitypackage) or [MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.AzureSpatialAnchors.2.12.0.unitypackage](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityLearning/releases/download/azure-spatial-anchors-v2.12.0/MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.AzureSpatialAnchors.2.12.0.unitypackage)
8. PUN 2 - FREE